# Find point-B on line by distance from point-A

Tags: python, math, geometry

I have line-equation, point-A and distance, and need to find point-B at the edge of the distance, on the line.
I have 2 equations:

```
distance = math.sqrt((pt1[0] - pt2[0])**2 + (pt1[1] - pt2[1])**2)
pt2[1] = m*pt2[0] + n
```

distance, pt1, m and n are known.

How can I implement this calculation in Python?
Maybe there is a Python library that can do this for me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the line `y=mx+b`, the slope `m` tells us the ratio between the change in x (`dx`) and the change in y (`dy`).

Math:

```
// Given
point_b = (point_a[0]+dx,point_a[1]+dy)
other_possible_point_b = (point_a[0]-dx,point_a[1]-dy)
dy = m*dx
x**2 + y**2 = distance

// Calculations
dx**2 + (m*dx)**2 = distance
(m**2+1)(dx**2) = distance
dx = sqrt(distance/(m**2+1))
dy = m*sqrt(distance/(m**2+1))
```

Python solution:

```
from math import sqrt

point_b = (point_a[0]+dx(distance,m), point_a[1]+dy(distance,m))
other_possible_point_b = (point_a[0]-dx(distance,m), point_a[1]-dy(distance,m)) # going the other way

def dy(distance, m):
    return m*dx(distance, m)

def dx(distance, m):
    return sqrt(distance/(m**2+1))
```

Comment: There is a mistake in the calculations. It should be `dx**2 + (m*dx)**2 = distance**2`

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that point A is not on the line. ( Even if it is, the solution will not be different)
You need to find the intersection between a circle and a line. It may have 1, 2 or 0 solutions.

```
(x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2 = d^2
y2 = m*x2 + c
```

The simplest solution would be:
Replace y2 by (m*x2 + c) in the first equation and solve the quadratic for x2.